# Run action for just one time in React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render

if i have an API call and i just wanna grape all data just once, at first time component run and not to cause any calls again at re-render.

Comment: I didn't know that parent is rerendered after child is changed... I thought it goes the way that if parent changes then children too (and thus rerendering)

Comment: This question is too vague. You need to add some details, and possibly code examples.

Comment: @BrianThompson actually it was an interview question so i have no idea how it should be in code, so i am wondering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass an empty array to useEffect's second arg.

```js
function App() {
  useEffect(() => console.log('runs once'), []);
}
```